# How to have square boxes with image and text

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to have two square div boxes in one line with some space between them. And both of them starts with an image at the top followed by a headline some text and a button at the bottom?

I've tried something with css:flex but ended up that it isn't possible to have both boxes the equal height and width and they had to be both a square.

My problem is that on image is a little bit higher then the other one and now I can't get two sqaures with the same size. Even if the images are the same then there is a different in the text. Maybe some more words on the left and so there is again a different height that I can't handle.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="example1.jpg" />
    <h2>Headline 1</h2>
    <p>Description 1</p>
    <button></button>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="example2.jpg" />
    <h2>Headline 2</h2>
    <p>Description 2 <br>with special line</p>
    <button></button>
  </div>
</div>

.wrapper { display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap;justfiy-content:space-between; width: 30vmax; }
.box { flex: 0 0 40%; height: 50%; text-align:center; }
```

## EDIT

Thanks for your work. It looks nearly the same as mine.
But unfortunately it isn't a square / quadrat in form.
That was my goal in the question.
I guess the problem is that a square / quadrat depends on its content. Or do I need javascript to achieve the height is equal to the width of the box.

Comment: what images are you using? can you set up a fiddle or is this live somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.box {
  flex: 0 0 40%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
button {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt="">
    <h2>Headline 1</h2>
    <p>Description 1</p>
    <button></button>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt="">
    <h2>Headline 2</h2>
    <p>Description 2
      <br>with special line</p>
    <button></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ynuu3ht/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper { 
  display:flex; 
  justify-content:space-between;
  width: 65vmax; 
  height:30vmax;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.box { 
  flex: 0 0 40%;
  height: 100%; 
  text-align:center; 
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="example1.jpg" />
    <h2>Headline 1</h2>
    <p>Description 1</p>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="example2.jpg" />
    <h2>Headline 2</h2>
    <p>Description 2 <br>with special line</p>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```